How to make my datatable reload with new data?
I am using ASP.NET MVC for a project and I have a datatable which is working fine when the page loads but when I submit a form for searching it returns the correct response in json but it does not display the data in the table rather just shows the json in browser.
DATA TABLE:
 var table;
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#customer_table').dataTable({
         clear: true,
         destroy: true,
         paging: true,
         processing: true,
         pageLength: 10,
         lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, 100000], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
         AutoWidth: false,
         "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
             $(this.api().table().container()).find('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
         },
         "ajax": {
             url: "/Home/GetCustomers",
             type: "POST",
             dataType: 'json',
             data: function (d) {
                 var formData = $('#searchForm').serializeArray();
                 formData.forEach(function (item) {
                     d[item.name] = item.value;
                 });
                 return d;
             },
             "dataSrc": function (json) {
                 var data = json;
                 json.draw = data.draw;
                 json.recordsTotal = data.recordsTotal;
                 json.recordsFiltered = data.recordsFiltered;
                 json.data = JSON.parse(data.data);
                 return json.data;
             }
         },
         destroy: true,
         "columns": [
             { "data": "customer_id" },
             { "data": "customer_id_external" },
             { "data": "customer_name" },
             { "data": "customer_user_name" },
             { "data": "customer_cnic" },
             { "data": "cusotmer_mobilenum" },
             { "data": "customer_address" },
             { "data": "package_id" },
             { "data": "join_date" },
             { "data": "customer_due_day" },
             { "data": "customer_status" },
             { "data": "TotalPaymentDue" },

         ]


     });

     $('#searchForm').on('Submit', function (e) {
         
         table.ajax.url('/Home/GetCustomers').load(); // Reload the DataTable with the new search data
     });

 })

I tried reloading the data table but it wont reload for some reason and keeps on showing plain json in browser.

you have to use data table .draw() to reload data tables with upcoming Ajax data. check on their platform for examples.

dataTable have default search,you can use searching to config it. Use custom search you can use form.Init function can write in a function.Call it in the ready function and search button click function.I use your code and complement the html and Action to realize the search function.I hope this can help you.
.cshtml:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <link href=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css
          type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection" /> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.7/css/materialize.min.css />
    <script src=https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.1.js></script>
     <script src=https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js></script> 
    <script>
           $(document).ready(function () {
            resetDataTable();
            $("#searchForm input[type=button]").on("click", function () {
                resetDataTable()
            })
        })
        function resetDataTable() {
            $('#customer_table').dataTable({
                searching: false,//show default search or not
                destroy: true,
                paging: true,
                processing: true,
                pageLength: 10,
                lengthMenu: [[10, 25, 50, 100, 100000], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
                AutoWidth: false,
                "initComplete": function (settings, json) {
                    $(this.api().table().container()).find('input').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
                },
                "ajax": {
                    url: "/Home/GetCustomers",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: function (d) {
                        var formData = $('#searchForm').serializeArray();
                        console.log(formData)
                        formData.forEach(function (item) {
                            d[item.name] = item.value;
                        });
                      
                        return d;
                    },
                    "dataSrc": function (json) {
 
                        return json.data;
                    }
                },
                destroy: true,
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "customer_id", title: 'customer_id' },
                    { "data": "customer_id_external", title: 'customer_id_external' },
                    { "data": "customer_name", title: 'customer_name' }
                ]
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="searchForm">
            <label asp-for="customer_id" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="customer_id" class="form-control" />
            <label asp-for="customer_name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="customer_name" class="form-control" />
            <input type="button" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
       
    </form>
    <table id="customer_table" >
    </table>
</body>
</html>

.controller.cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult GetCustomers(string customer_id = "",string customer_name="")
{
     Console.WriteLine(customer_id, customer_name);
     List<Customer> ListData = new List<Customer>();
     int recordsTotal = 0;
 
     DateTime aDate = DateTime.Now;
 
     
     Customer dm = new Customer();
     dm.customer_id = 1;
     dm.customer_id_external = "111";
     dm.customer_name = "Silly";
 
     Customer dm1 = new Customer();
     dm1.customer_id = 2;
     dm1.customer_id_external = "222";
     dm1.customer_name = "John";
   
     Customer dm11 = new Customer();
     dm11.customer_id = 3;
     dm11.customer_id_external = "333";
     dm11.customer_name = "Mathew";
     ListData.Add(dm);
     ListData.Add(dm1);
     ListData.Add(dm11);
 
     recordsTotal = ListData.Count();
 
     var jsonData = new
     {
         draw = 1,
         recordsFiltered = recordsTotal,
         recordsTotal = recordsTotal,
         data = ListData
     };
    
     return Ok(jsonData);
}

The result is :

